# Get input value with javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm a newbie and new on javascript.
I was following some suggestion to get value from an input.
What I need is a value from that input when I pressed enter to put in a query.

I have an input

```
<input id="search" type="text" placeholder="Search here" onkeyup="getval(this)"></input>
```

and this is my script on my php page

```
function getval(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        alert(e.value);
    }
}
```

But that doesn't work. No alert appear.

Comment: You are calling `getval(this)`, so `e` is `this`, the input element. You want to call `getval.call(this,event)` and then you can use `e.which` and `this.value`.

Comment: @Niet Could you please show me the code?
I'm so new on javascript (and stackoverflow).

Comment: I literally gave you all the pieces you need.

Answer (score 0):

can you use jquery on your page?

if so...

`$("#search").keyup(function(){
  alert($(this).val());
});`

Comment: @J nui
I just can't understand why it won't work when I tried it on my code meanwhile it's good on your jsfiddle.
Maybe it wasn't the javascript that is the problem.